# Recursion not working for multiple levels

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a recursion function but its doesn't seem to work for multiple levels, which it should cause its recursion. any ideas where i'm going wrong?

```
      function productData(elem) {
        console.log("elem 1", elem)

        if (elem[0]) {
          if (elem[0].hasChildNodes()) {
            elem[0].childNodes.forEach(function (item) {
              console.log("item", item)
              console.log("item", item.childNodes)
              productData(item);
            });
          }
        }
      }

const product = document.querySelectorAll('[itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"]');

  productData(product)
```

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't working on multiple levels?  Do you mean some things are missing from levels or levels don't exist at all?

Comment: Your code seems to expect that `elem` is a `NodeList` or array-like object containing elements, yet when you recursively call your method, you're passing in a single element.  I expect that you're seeing an error in your browser's console, as DOM elements aren't array-like.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem along with proper explanation of expectations

Comment: You are only iterating through elem[0], Remove the index and try

Comment: See my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

If I select the html tag and run your code through it, it is spitting out the children nodes.

```html
 var productData = function(elem) {
    console.log("elem 1", elem)

    if (elem[0]) {
      if (elem[0].hasChildNodes()) {
        elem[0].childNodes.forEach(function (item) {
          console.log("item", item)
          console.log("item", item.childNodes)
          productData(item);
        });
      }
    }
  }
  
productData(document.querySelectorAll('html'));
```

Output from when I ran locally:
[image]

Do you have an example of the HTML page you're trying to read? Maybe the element you're selecting really doesn't have a child node.

Also, what are you trying to do specifically? This almost looks like a breadth-first search kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the array index access on `elem` since in the forEach loop, only one item gets passed.

```
 function productData(elem) {
    console.log("elem 1", elem)

    if (elem) {
      if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
        elem.childNodes.forEach(function (item) {
          console.log("item", item)
          console.log("item", item.childNodes)
          productData(item);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thats gives .hasChildNodes is not a function